# Convert user id to user name in a single rest query that gets list items

Tags: 2013, rest, odata, spuser

So I get some items from a list via a rest query, and in the Creator field I get an ID. I want to display the name of the user and not the ID. Calling the GetUserByID isn't an option because it might be 100+ calls and I am using angular to bind the data, so it won't fit pretty well.

I've looked in FieldValuesAsHtml, AsText and ForEdit, none of which gives the name. How can I get the name in the same query?

Comment: Look at the following comment. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22483105/5878778

Comment: @RamanaViswanadha I actually just found a blog from a google search that said the same. Thank you very much! Pretty silly though that this is "hidden" in the link area of the data you recieve...

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution. Just submit the solution and mark it as an answer so that this post can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up finding the answer at http://sympmarc.com/2014/01/21/getting-user-information-with-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api/

But a much "cleaner" answer can be found in Ramana's comment, without unnecessary explanations.